# How to position Label Widgets inside the BoxLayout correctly

Tags: python, kivy

I had this python code with kv which has a ScrollView widget that enables me to scroll horizontally and vertically.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

main_kv = """

ScrollView:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint: (None, None)
        width: self.minimum_width
        height: self.minimum_height

        Label:
            text: "A veryyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy long text."
            font_size: sp(30)
            size_hint: (None, None)
            height: dp(30)
            width: self.texture_size[0]

"""

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(main_kv)

TestApp().run()
```

The above code works... but my goal is to add a button that when pressed, the BoxLayout widget will add a new Label widget..

I tried to modify the code with this but:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.metrics import dp, sp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


main_kv = """

<Main>:

    ScrollView:

        BoxLayout:
            id: boxlayout_id
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint: (None, None)
            width: self.minimum_width
            height: self.minimum_height

            Label:
                text: "A veryyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy long text."
                font_size: sp(30)
                size_hint: (None, None)
                height: dp(30)
                width: self.texture_size[0]

    Button:
        text: "Add Label"
        on_press: root.add_newlabel()          
"""


class Main(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()

        self.orientation = "vertical"

    def add_newlabel(self, *args):
        newLabel = Label()
        newLabel.text = " A veryyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy long text."
        newLabel.font_size = sp(30)
        newLabel.size_hint = (None, None)
        newLabel.height = dp(30)
        newLabel.width = newLabel.texture_size[0]

        self.ids.boxlayout_id.add_widget(newLabel)


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):       
        Builder.load_string(main_kv)      
        return Main()               

TestApp().run()
```

The problem of the modified code is that the newLabel widgets' position is odd.

Let's look at this image.

The image below is the output (not yet clicking the Button).

[image]

It's normal and okay.

The image below is the output after I clicked the Button widget thrice.

[image]

As we can see, the three newLabel widgets' x position is sligthly off.

I tried to analyze what was the cause of this problem but I can't figure it out.

I will appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: yes Sir @eyllanesc. That's what I want as an output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a new Label and adding the properties each time you add, you can create a template and add it.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

main_kv = """
<CustomLabel>:
    font_size: sp(30)
    size_hint: (None, None)
    multiline:True
    size: self.texture_size

<Main>:
    scroll_view: sv
    boxlayout: boxlayout_id
    ScrollView:
        id: sv
        BoxLayout:
            id: boxlayout_id
            orientation: "vertical"
            height: self.minimum_height
            size_hint: (None, None)

    Button:
        text: "Add Label"
        on_press: root.add_newlabel()          
"""

class CustomLabel(Label):
    pass

class Main(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.orientation = "vertical"
    def add_newlabel(self, *args):
        newLabel = CustomLabel()
        newLabel.text = " A veryyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy long text."
        self.boxlayout.add_widget(newLabel)
        self.scroll_view.scroll_to(newLabel)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):       
        Builder.load_string(main_kv)      
        return Main()               

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks Sir. It worked and I will try to learn about kv templates.